# Android Studio - Could not find com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5

Tags: android, firebase

When rebuilding project, build fails and gives the following warning:

Could not find com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5.

If I click "Search in build.gradle files" and open build.gradle,

I can see: implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'

Any tips appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JobDispatcher is old, deprecated, and no longer available.  You should use WorkManager instead.

If you must absolutely use JobDispatcher, which I do not recommend, you can find the source code archived [here](https://github.com/googlearchive/firebase-jobdispatcher-android).

Read about [how to migrate from JobDispatcher to WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/migrating-fb).

Comment: Thanks Doug for the pointer, looking into it.